# Css align element left

Tags: html, css

[image]

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nu558?file=/demo.js)

As you can see from the image I have a toggle, I should place it on the right.

But if I use display: block, but it gives problems.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: if `display: block;` gives you unknown problems, don't use it. Take a look at CSS flex. `margin-left: auto;` on your custom toggler should than help.

Comment: Paul, just to hint you about the downvotes, please, next time you should put all the relevant **minimal** code right within your answer. Don't post full blown examples (unless really necessary) since such could discourage answerers. Please read [mcve], and also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
}

.top .toggler {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="top">
  <span>&#x2630;</span>
  <span class="toggler">ON/OFF</span>
</header>
```

or simply like:

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header class="top">
  <span>&#x2630;</span>
  <span>ON/OFF</span>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't know why they downvote you @Roko, it's correct. But you can actually remove the `.top .toogler` values and just add `justify-content: space-between` to the `.top` class.

Comment: It seems to work, I don't understand why they put negative ratings.
Even my question got negative marks.

Comment: @MarkBurns: I also tried as you say, but it's not working for me.

Comment: @Paul added an example to express Mark's suggestion.